# Adding 0 to Plotly Axis in R

Tags: r, plotly, shiny

I'm pretty new to Plotly for R, and R for that matter, but I'm having trouble showing the last value on my bar graph. It looks like it's using the smallest value as the baseline and not actually 0.

The line of code I'm using to produce the graph is

```
plot_ly(data[which(data$CURR_DLQ %in% input$dlqType),], x=~DLQ_PCT, y=~CURR_DLQ,  type="bar", orientation = "h", color=~CURR_DLQ, colors = c("#CADC64", "#91CA6E", "#60B579", "#3A9E80", "#278580", "#2B6B77")) %>% hide_colorbar()
```

not sure if there's a way to hard code that the baseline be 0. Any help will be appreciated!

[plotly image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGbiC.png)

Comment: try adding `layout(
    xaxis = list(rangemode = "tozero"),
    yaxis = list(rangemode = "tozero"))`

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything, i also tried range = c(0,7) or range = c(-1,7) but didn't work, seems like it's not even recognizing that small percentage amount.

Comment: maybe add `tick0 = 0` within the axis property list as proposed by @missuse?

Comment: still didn't fix the issue. What's weird is if I change the x-axis to use the count number, it shows the value for the CURR_DLQ = 6 but when I try to use the DLQ_PCT it doesn't show the value for the CURR_DLQ = 6. So I'm not sure if it's a plotly thing that it doesn't plot very tiny values.